# Redux Dispatch updates state but does not update the component the first time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

Using redux toolkit to update the state with data from a CSV file. The state updates properly but the component only renders after the file is uploaded again.
Here is the action slice:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export let dataUploadSlice = createSlice({
  name: "dataUpload",
  initialState: {
    value: [],
  },

  reducers: {
    uploadFile: (state, action) => {
      return { ...state, value: action.payload };
    },

    removeFile: (state) => {
      state.value = [];
    },
  },
});

export const { uploadFile, removeFile } = dataUploadSlice.actions;

export default dataUploadSlice.reducer;
```

and here is the data upload component using Papaparse;

```
// Redux
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { uploadFile, removeFile } from "../features/dataupload/dataUploadSlice";

const UploadDataGrid = () => {
  const gridStyle = { minHeight: 440 };

  const dataFile = useSelector((state) => state.dataUpload.value);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [colHeader, setColHeader] = useState([]);
  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([]);
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");

  const handleFileUpload = (e) => {
    const files = e.target.files;

    Papa.parse(files[0], {
      complete: function (results) {
        setFileName(e.target.files[0].name);
        //console.log(e.target.files[0].name);

        // Dispatch the data to the table in store
        dispatch(uploadFile(results.data));

        let columnHeaders = dataFile[0].map((item) => {
          return { name: item, header: item, minWidth: 50, defaultFlex: 1 };
        });
        setColHeader(columnHeaders);
        let dataSources = dataFile.slice(1).map((item, index) => {
          var dict = {};
          for (var i = 0; i < dataFile[0].length; i++) {
            dict[dataFile[0][i]] = item[i];
          }
          dict["id"] = index;
          return dict;
        });

        setDataSource(dataSources);
      },
    });
  };
```

`dataFile` in the above code only updates after I upload the file again but the state is updated correctly every time. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Tried other ways of assigning objects but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same function/scope, you cannot get the immediate value from store that is updated with the `dispatch`.

Only perform dispatch in the `handleFileUpload` function:

```js
const handleFileUpload = (e) => {
  const { files } = e.target;
  Papa.parse(files[0], {
    complete(results) {
      setFileName(e.target.files[0].name);
      // Dispatch the data to the table in store
      dispatch(uploadFile(results.data));
    },
  });
};
```

and `setDataSource` when `dataFile` is updated (dispatch updates this state). For this use `useEffect`:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!dataFile) return;
    const columnHeaders = dataFile[0].map((item) => ({
      name: item,
      header: item,
      minWidth: 50,
      defaultFlex: 1,
    }));
    setColHeader(columnHeaders);
    const dataSources = dataFile.slice(1).map((item, index) => {
      const dict = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < dataFile[0].length; i++) {
        dict[dataFile[0][i]] = item[i];
      }
      dict.id = index;
      return dict;
    });

    setDataSource(dataSources);
  }, [dataFile]);
```

Think `dispatch` like it is `setState` from the `const [state , setState] = useState()` and the value from `useSelector` like the `state` value. First you need to set the state and watch this update within `useEffect` like hook that has dependency array.